# Kolab on the Pi

Tags: software-installation, server

I'm about to aquire a Pi to replace my mail server, and wanted to go with [Kolab](http://kolab.org/) here, most likely using Raspian as a base. They have their own repo, but concentrate on i386 and amd64. Checking for support of the ARMHF architecture in general, and the Pi in special, I only found a lot of people asking whether it were possible – but answers, if at all, were only as detailed as "yes", "somebody/I did it", or "X should know (but X doesn't talk much)".

With X often being Andreas Cordes, I've of course checked his site for [Kolab on ARMHF architecture](http://whvneo.blogspot.de/) – and indeed he's got a detailed description on [how to ***build*** the packages](http://whvneo.blogspot.de/p/preparation.html). I don't want to start building packages everytime there are updates (I simply lack the time). So I'd prefer to go with the alternative he provides "for the impatient", mentioning his repository. Unfortunately, that ends with "then install with aptitude the metapackage kolab ***and solve the dependencies manually because I didn't override the priority in the packages information"*** (emphasis mine) – with no details on what to expect at that end: might be trivial or complex, and I'm afraid of the latter ;).

As for configuration: My "raw plans" are currently to have all software on the Pi directly (SDCard), while placing all data (and, if possible, specific configurations) on external disk – for "fast-and-easy switching" in case of "emergency" (hardware/software failures).

> **TL;DR:**
>
> Has anyone successfully installed Kolab on a Pi, and can provide easy-to-follow steps?

As said, I'm thinking about using Raspian as a base. But not even having the hardware obtained yet, I'm open for other "starters" as well. Would be great if the instructions would also match for a BananaPi (which they should with Raspian; little differences or "unsureness" pointed out is fine), in case the performance of a RasPi fails the requirements ;)

**Edit:** as I was asked whether ARMv6 or ARMv7: with the former being rather "oddballs", I prefer the latter (again speaking for compatibility with the BPi). My main goal is to get Kolab running on it smoothly, with as few "trip hazards" as possible plus ease of maintenance.

Comment: You should indicate whether this is for a Pi 2 or an A/B/+.   For the former, you can use ARMv7 binaries, which are usually what is currently meant when someone refers to arm stuff without any further context.   For the latter, you need ARMv6 binaries, which are oddball.   Either way, most likely you'll have to work through this yourself -- if you do get it to work out, please come back and answer your own question for posterity.

Comment: Thanks, @goldilocks – and as indicated by mentioning the BananaPi (and if I'm correctly informed on this), it is ARMv7 then. As said, I have not yet obtained the device – so with ARMv6 being rather "oddballs", I'd then definitely go with an ARMv7 one :)

Comment: Oh! My Google-Fu works again! I've just found a repo offering ARMv7 Kolab packages: http://packages.der-he.de/packages/ – looks promising, though marked "testing only". Not tested that yet (how can I, with no device available) – so I'm leaving this as a comment for now. Of course, once I've tested it and it worked out, I'll make it a full-fledged answer with instructions – Q&A style, as usual ;)

Comment: Just to clarify because of your edit: There are 5 models of Pi, the A, the B, the A+, the B+, and the 2 (aka. 2B).   The first four are all ARMv6 only, and single core.  The last one is ARMv7 (but ARMv7 is backward compatible with ARMv6) and quad core.  Confusing the issue, the B+ and 2 have identical form factors (they look about the same).   The form factor of the A is more like the B, and the A+ more like the B+/2.   The A/A+ is a bit cheaper than the B/B+/2, which all cost the same (at least from the base distributors). Hopefully you know which one is coming to your door ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for those really useful details, @goldilocks! I'm completely new to the Pi area, so I welcome all hints. With your last comment, I'll need to take a closer look at the "2" (ARMv7 with 4-core sounds intriguing); I was already fixing the BPi (btw: as [help/on-topic] doesn't state explicitly, are questions on and around the BPi welcome here as well? Or should I better raise that on Meta as it wasn't yet decided?)

Comment: Questions about any model of pi are welcome here.  You probably want a B+ or a 2.  I've read somewhere the main reason they continue to produce the A and B is for industrial clients that want to keep the same form factor.  However, the pre-+ models have power issues that are corrected in the + and the 2, and at least IMO the newer form factor is more convenient (all ports/jacks/plugs are on two sides, rather than spread around all four).   And of course, the 2 has 4 cores and twice the memory of the B+, and (significantly, as you see) can run ARMv7 stuff (much more choice of OS).

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I'll probably go for the Banana nonetheless (Gigabit Ethernet is an argument for a server, though it will probably be just "half Gigabit" if it's really attached to the USB2.0 – and the DualCore should be sufficient). I will report back when I've got the hardware and played with that repo (answer on success, including essentials from these comments so we can clean them up; comment on fail). Might take a few weeks, though.